# Битрикс получить id свойства по названию через API

Tags: php, битрикс

Предположим, что есть свойство по названию "Артикул". Есть инфоблок с ID `INFOBLOCK_ID`.

Как программно узнать, есть ли у элементов данного инфоблока свойство "Артикул"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так работает:

```
$arFilter = array(
    'IBLOCK_ID' => INFOBLOCK_ID,
    'NAME' => 'Артикул',
);
$res = CIBlockProperty::GetList(array(), $arFilter);
$field = $res->Fetch();
if ($field) {
    echo 'Ура, свойство есть!';
}
```